# what would it take to build a wifi repeater with the PicoW?

Tags: pi-pico-w

as far as i can tell from experimentation, the radio on the Raspberry PicoW cards is not capable of dual mode functions - it can only work as a station, or as an access point - it cannot do both at once.

i am limited to micro-python, however, and perhaps it cannot support this.  i have not tried to do it in C, as yet.

can anyone can correct me, or show me how to make dual mode radio work on picoW?

presuming i need a second radio,i can connect a wifi board over one of the UART channels.

but what will it take, in software, to connect these, to make a wifi repeater?

can anyone point me in the right direction, to learn about these things?

any advice very much appreciated..

Answer (score -1):

You should switch to Raspberry Pi Zero W instead. With Pico W it may not be possible to make a wifi repeater/extender. Even if possible, the process will not be straightforward and you will not find any guideline from the internet.